# Access violation exception when trying to call flash function from c# app

Tags: c#, .net, flash, exception, axshockwaveflash

My program is windows forms application with swf inside it. I have such c# code:

```
string invokeXmlString = "<invoke name=\"" + methodName + "\" returntype=\"xml\"><arguments><string>" +
response + "</string></arguments></invoke>";
if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( this.FlashApplication.Movie ) )
{
   this.FlashApplication.CallFunction(invokeXmlString);
}
```

And I'm getting `System.AccessViolationException` on this line:

`if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( this.FlashApplication.Movie ) )`

Can someone help me with solving this issue? Or at least pointing me where can I find solution to this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove the if part and try , string.IsNullOrEmpty shouldn't give that error.

Comment: ok, I'll try that, thanks for help! but why is this happening?

Comment: The flash file might be having restrictions for IIS user.